# Iphone network Programming

Tags: ios

I'm new for IOS programming. I want to send data to iPhone via TCP/IP protocol using WiFi network. I have already done with client to send data. I want to known Iphone can be a server that receive data and display on the screen? Server have to listening on port from client what would i suppose to use command or method? any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Have a look at [this page](http://englishtips.org/coursebooks/). 2. Google `NSNetService`, `CFNetwork` and `BSD sockets tutorial`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this could be helpful for you: https://github.com/fpotter/socketio-cocoa

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iPhone can act as server.

An easy way out would be using Robbie Hanson's wrapper
called [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).

It comes with server examples. I believe server code is written for OSX
but it can be easily converted for iOS usage.

One problem that you might encounter is discoverability - finding 
the current IP of the device - you can overcome this problem using
Bonjour, but that is another topic. Pretty easy to implement though.